# Android javax.crypto.BadPaddingException

Tags: android, encryption

I am implementing encryption/decryption to my files. code is given below. I can't find out the problem. 
Am I missing anything? I need to implement 128 bit AES Encryption. 
Is there anything wrong? 
It end up with error

```
 "javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e06b065:Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:BAD_DECRYPT"
```

Please help me.

```
private static byte[] encodeFile(byte[] yourKey, byte[] fileData)
        throws Exception {
    byte[] encrypted = null;
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(yourKey, 0, yourKey.length, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7PADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    encrypted = cipher.doFinal(fileData);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    byte[] keyStart = "This is my key".getBytes();
    String id = "dummypass";
    int iterationCount = 1000;
    int saltLength = 32;
    int keyLength = 128;
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = Arrays.copyOf(keyStart,saltLength);
    random.nextBytes(salt);
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(id.toCharArray(), salt,
            iterationCount, keyLength);
    SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory
            .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        keyBytes = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec).getEncoded();
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    return key.getEncoded();
}

private static byte[] decodeFile(byte[] yourKey, byte[] encryptedData)
        throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(yourKey, 0, yourKey.length,
            "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7PADDING");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
    return decrypted;
}

public static void Encrypt(byte[] bytesToEncrypt, File target) {
    try {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(target));
        byte[] key = generateKey();
        byte[] encryptedBytes = encodeFile(key, bytesToEncrypt);
        bos.write(encryptedBytes);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static  byte[] DecryptFile(byte[] bytesToDecrypt) {
    byte[] decodedData = new byte[0];
    try {
        byte[] key = generateKey();
        decodedData = decodeFile(key, bytesToDecrypt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decodedData;
}
```

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret.  Do not report any passing errors on decryption.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Verify that `key` is the same in both `Encrypt` and `DecryptFile`.

Since both call `generateKey` and `generateKey` calls `SecureRandom` `nextBytes` the keys are going to be different.

You need to save the encryption key for use during decryption.

Comment: Could you please mention an effect way to generate ideal keys for both encryption and decryption??

Comment: On encryption create a key with `generateKey`, save that key for decryption and pass it into the decryption function. Note: AES is symmetric encryption and uses the same key for both encryption and decryption.

Comment: If I use CBC instead of EBC, I need to mention a random IV. right? So do I need to save the IV also for the decryption??

Comment: My question comment: Use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to not secret. IOW, on encryption create a 16-byte random sequence and concatenate the IV followed by the encrypted data. On decryption just split the data into the IV and encrypted data and use the IV for decryption. With ECB mode similar messages will have similar encrypted data and that may help the attacker.

Comment: @Alvin Varghese: Yes, you need to save IV for key generation for decryption if the decryption side does not receive the key by some means.